# Array index not working from within $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, web-scraping

The program I'm working on has an array with a bunch of web addresses in it, e.g:

```
var urls = ["http://www.url.com/page1", "http://www.url.com/page2", "http://www.url.com/page3"];
```

Then I loop through this array in order to run some code based on each web address:

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    $.get(urls[i], function(response) {
        console.log(urls[i]);
    });
```

I'm using the $.get to extract data from another page on the site, and my problem is that the console.log shows undefined? Even more strange is that if I pass url[1], or any value as a number into the console.log, then it returns the url from the array is intended?

Furthermore, if I just log the current for loop index like

```
console.log([i]);
```

then it just outputs 3, three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a closure in order to preserve the **i** variable. The contest of the variable is global, and when the for ends the value is urls.length + 1. Instead, if you close the code in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) you preserve the value of your variable because it gets a function scope.

With modern browsers you may use

> [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of var: declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

Change:

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
$.get(url[i], function(response) {
    console.log(urls[i]);
});
```

To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  (function (i) {
      $.get(url[i], function(response) {
          console.log(urls[i]);
      });
  })(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an asynchronous issue. When the inner function gets called, `i === urls.length` because the outer `for` loop has already finished.

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    // The anonymous function won't get called until the for loop completes
    // and you get a response back from the url.
    $.get(urls[i], function(response) {
        // When this finally gets called, the for loop has already completed
        // and i === urls.length, AKA undefined
        console.log(urls[i]);
    });
}
```

You can use `let` to fix your issue:

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    // This will scope the variable to this for loop.
    let url = urls[i];
    $.get(url, function(response) {
        console.log(url);
    });
}
```

Comment: or just change `var i` to `let i`